# Discard Windows text and app size on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I made a WPF .exe and I wish that the look is the same, also in the pc where the zoom factor for text and app is 100% or more than 100%.

it's possible to do this by code? do something like lock the zoom factor for my program to 100%?

thanks in advance

Comment: Locking the zoom factor will **not help** your application for **accessibility**. Why are you trying to lock the zoom factor? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: 'cause it's a game menu launcher and if is over 100% all the things go out of the screen

Comment: I tried with `[assembly: System.Windows.Media.DisableDpiAwareness]` on `AssemblyInfo.cs` but nothing changes...